# Android: Handle different type of value with GSON

Tags: android, json, gson

In my app, I get and parse a JSON stream from a wordpress (RESP API v2) website.

I use, **OKHTTP**, **RETROFIT** with **GSON** converter to read and parse the stream into my objects.

Usually, my GSON converter expect an object but, because of a recent update, the website gives me a boolean (false). The value isn't set yet.

This is my question: *"Can I handle different type of values for the same variable name with GSON Serialize and how?"*

Thank you!

---

This is my object:

```
public static class StageProfileImage {





        //////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Variables
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////
        @SerializedName("url")
        private String stageProfileImageUri;
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////





        //////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Setters & Getters
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////
        public String getStageProfileImageUri() {
            return stageProfileImageUri;
        }
        public void setStageProfilUri(String stageProfileImageUri) {
            this.stageProfileImageUri = stageProfileImageUri;
        }
        /////////////////////////////////////////////





    }
```

**Important:** I can't modify the stream.

Answer (score 0):

try @SerializedName(value = "url", alternate = {"altkey1", "altkey2"})

Edit: Changed to a more generic example.

Comment: If you want parse multiple values for same key. You can either use a custom gson TypeAdapter or return ResponseBody as response and Parse it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but it isn't my problem. In fact, GSON can't convert the stream from the website because instead of this:

```
"stage_profile_image" : {
  ...
}
```

My stream give me that:

```
"stage_profile_image" : false
```

In the first one, I get an object but in the second one I get a boolean which is not the type of value it expects and GSON is unable to do the convertion.